# Как сделать переворот танка в сторону его движения?Не выходя за данные библиотеки?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image

win = Tk()
win.title('Танки 1998')
win.geometry(f'600x600')
win.resizable(False,False)
win['bg'] = 'black'
bg = Canvas(win, bg='black',width=600,height=600)
bg.pack() 
h=600
w=600
class Wall():
    def __init__(self,x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2):
        self.x_1 = x_1
        self.y_1 = y_1
        self.x_2 = x_2
        self.y_2 = y_2
        bg.create_rectangle(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,fill='brown',outline='gray')
        # bg.create_line(x_1,x_2,(y_2-y_1)/3,fill='white')#Сделать дизайн стенам

        
wall_1 = Wall(50,50,100,550)
wall_2 = Wall(50,50,250,100)
wall_4 = Wall(500,50,550,550)
wall_3 = Wall(350,50,550,100)
wall_5 = Wall(50,500,250,550)
wall_6 = Wall(350,500,550,550)


class Tank:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 270
        self.y = 570
        self.photo_tank = PhotoImage(file='tank.png')
        self.tanks_s = bg.create_image(self.x,self.y,image = self.photo_tank)

        
    def up(self, event):
        bg.move(self.tanks_s, 0, -5)
        
    def down(self, event):
        bg.move(self.tanks_s, 0, 5)
      
       
        
    def right(self,event):
        bg.move(self.tanks_s,5,0)

        
    def left(self,event):
        bg.move(self.tanks_s,-5,0)

        



tank = Tank()


win.bind('<Key-Up>', tank.up)
win.bind('<Key-Down>', tank.down)
win.bind('<Key-Left>', tank.left)
win.bind('<Key-Right>', tank.right)





win.mainloop()
```

Comment: А что у вас получилось и что не получается?

Comment: У меня получилось сделать танк и стены. А надо сделать так нажимаешь на езду вверх танк смотрит наверх, нажимаешь на движение в них танк смотри вниз картинку короче крутить. Не используя другие библиотеки

Comment: Я имею ввиду вы когда нажимаете на кнопку не чего не происходит? У PIL.Image.Image вроде есть rotate, попробуйте.

Comment: Нет ну посмотрите

Comment: Что нет? И что посмотреть?